# Will SQLite work fine for this?

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

I am working on a small app that will need a database, I was thinking about using sqlite but I am worried about if its going to do the job right and mainly about speed.

I will have a table with columns like: id - keyword - link1 - link2 - link3

And I will need to run queries like 'select * from table where link1 = ""' and also '---link1 LIKE '%something%'

I would have from 5k to 50k entries on each database (i will use multiple dbs).

Will SQLite work fine for this type of queries or it can get slow for this amount of entries?

Comment: Look at SQLITE recommandations http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html, and decide if is the right tool.

Comment: I had in mind using threads (forking php scripts), but I could setup one "thread" to handle all the db inserts so it wont conflict. I think that could work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQLite has a pretty old speed comparison test on their site](http://www.sqlite.org/speed.html).  It's a bit dated, but still pretty relevant as neither PostgreSQL nor MySQL have made any major barrier breaking improvements in their speed.

Comment: Just as a note, I don't think those PostgreSQL results are reliable.